# how do I delete an aws configure profile?

Tags: aws-cli

To create a custom configure profile in aws cli I am using the following command:

```
aws configure --profile user1
```

However, I cannot find any command to delete one of my profiles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi you need a command or do you just need remove the profile?

You can edit the:
Windows

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\.AWS\credentials
C:\Users\USERNAME\.AWS\config
    
(%USERPROFILE%\.aws\config 
%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials)
```

***or***

Linux and macOS

```
~/.aws/config ~/.aws/credentials
~/.aws/config ~/.aws/config
```

If you were worried about do it many times, you can create a script with powershell or sed…

```
Get-Content test.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "<profile>", "" } | Set-Content C:\Users\USERNAME.AWS\config
```

Or

```
sed -i 's/"[profile profile]//g' ~/.aws/config
```

Important: you need write the replace to all lines regarding your unless profile and I should do it too for your credentials file.